# Importing Existing Eclipse Projects into Liferay IDE

Tags: liferay

I'm trying to convert a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse into a Liferay Project (ultimately a portlet).

I create my DWP, but I don't see the option to Convert to Liferay project when I right-clilck.

In the Liferay Docs, it states:

> Note: If you don't have a convert action available it means either
>   that the project is already a Liferay IDE project, or that it is not
>   faceted (i.e., Java and Dynamic Web project facets are not yet
>   configured). Configure accordingly before moving on.

What do they mean by "Configure accordingly" and how can I accomplish this?

Comment: It might be that the portlet is not present in the plugins SDK of liferay. I m not sure

Comment: That is something Eclipse would tell me if it ever gave me the option to convert it into a portlet

Comment: Or the project might not be faceted i.e. the project Facets might not have been configured. Which version of Liferay IDE are you using?

Comment: 6.2 I believe, unless I'm looking at the wrong version #

Comment: I did built a DWP in 6.1 IDE and in developer studio, & I was able to see the convert project. AFAIK 6.2 is beta, hope its not a defect.

Comment: Looks like I had an older version of Liferay IDE installed; updating now and I'll get back to you